# How to use @RequestBody and @RequestParam together

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm trying to use both `@RequestBody` and `@RequestParam` to send JSON and multiple files through Postman but it's not working. Is it possible to use both annotations in an API?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save/product/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> save(@Valid @RequestBody ProductVo productVo, @RequestParam("files") @NotNull @NotBlank MultipartFile[] uploadfiles) {

    System.out.println("body " + productVo.toString());
    for (MultipartFile file :  uploadfiles) {
        System.out.println(file.getOriginalFilename());
        System.out.println(file.getContentType());
        System.out.println(file.getName());
        System.out.println(file.getSize());

    }
    return new ResponseEntity<APIResponse>(this.apiResponse, HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
}
```

Comment: `RequestParam` is for query parameters *in the URL*, which I doubt is how you're passing your files.

Comment: @jonrsharpe i now that point files also by attache with Url

Comment: Current i have to 2 question in my mind which i'm trying to solve 1 ) how we send the file under the POJO class 2) how we use the above case

Comment: one of answer i implement this way https://github.com/NABEEL-AHMED-JAMIL/file-uploader/tree/master/Fserver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ease your life by wrapping the multipart alongside the other fields:

```
  class UploadContext {

    private MultipartFile file;
    private UserCreateRequest request;
    // other fields
 }
```

and use this object in the controller:

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/upload")
    public void upload(UploadContext context) {
        // controller logic here
    }
```

Doc: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-multipart-forms

In your client code you have to clear the content-type from the headers:

```
     headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

@RequestParam takes parameter from uri, you are actually trying to achieve something else.

Here is an example controller takes json body and multipart file :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

    UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public UserController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @PostMapping({"/", ""})
    public ResponseEntity<User> post(@RequestPart("request") UserCreateRequest request, @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {

        String photoPath = UUID.randomUUID() + file.getOriginalFilename().replaceAll(" ", "").trim();

        // other logic

        return ResponseEntity.ok(userService.create(request));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Emre i use your code after update when i send the request by use of curl `curl -i -X POST 'localhost:9191/save/product/test' -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "request={ "productName" : "nabeel", "price" : 2500.0, "status": 0, "catList" : [1,2,3] }" -F "files=@C:/Users/AdMaxim/Desktop/check this.png"` it's show this message  **{"timestamp":"2018-08-19T12:44:36.626+0000","status":415,"error":"Unsupported Media Type","message":"Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported","path":"/save/product/test"}**

Comment: Hi @user2738014 I'm using macOs and I successfully send request via curl with command : `curl -i -X POST \
-H 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed' \
-F 'request={ "name" : "nabeel" };type=application/json' \
-F 'file=@/Users/emre/Desktop/creativity.jpg' \
http://localhost:8080/users`

Answer (score 1):

Any number of files and a string param can be uploaded by having a `MultipartHttpServletRequest` and `RequestParam`.

One thing to be aware of: The `MultipartHttpServletRequest` will also hold all the request params, so technically you can even just have `MultipartHttpServletRequest` and parse it

Signature of Controller is:

```
public ResponseEntity<BulkUploadResponsePayload> filesAndJson(
            @ApiParam(hidden = true) MultipartHttpServletRequest multipartRequest,
            @RequestParam(value = "json-param",name = "json-param") String documentType) {
     // multipartRequest will have all the files
     // you can use json-param for any string
}
```